# Part for DC Fan in EagleCAD

Tags: dc-motor, schematics, eaglecad, fan

I have been designing a circuit that involves a 5V DC Fan. When I was creating the schematic on EagleCAD, I couldn't find something that resembles a Fan other than a Motor. Should I stick with using a motor, or should I opt to find a library that contains a much more intended symbol for a fan elsewhere?

TIA

Comment: What do you intend to do with the schematic? Normally we would add a component that is the **connector** for the fan, not a component for the fan itself. That assumes that you want to build a PCB from the Eagle design.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson At the moment, the system is still at the prototype stage. I need the schematic to submit it along with the system so it has to be clear as much as possible.

Comment: The steady state load for any 5V fan looks like a resistor with surges depending the rate of change of voltage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I stick with using a motor, or should I opt to find a library
> that contains a much more intended symbol for a fan elsewhere?

You forgetting the third and simplest option - just create your own symbol. You can also add connector footprint for it to be ready for PCB design.

Seriously, I don't recall any more or less complex projects where I did not need at least one custom element.